# Using regex to calculate the number of ints within a data set [Perl]

Tags: regex, perl

I am having difficulty with a certain set of regex that needs to be solved to calculate the frequency of positive, negative, and 0 integers within the data set inside of the sample code.  I have successfully gotten it to solve the negative integers, but no such luck with positive and 0.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my ( $ctrP, $ctrN, $ctrZ ) = ( 0, 0, 0 );
while( my $num = <DATA> ) {
        chomp($num);
        ## print "num=[$num]\n";
        if ( $num =~ /^-\d+$/ ) {
                $ctrN++;
        }
        elsif ( $num =~ /^[1-9]\d*$/ ) {
                $ctrZ++;
        }
        else {
                $ctrP++;
        }
}
printf("freq(Z+):%8s\n", $ctrP );
printf("freq(Z-):%8s\n", $ctrN );
printf("freq(0):%9s\n", $ctrZ );
printf("Total:%11s\n", ($ctrP+$ctrN+$ctrZ) );
exit;
__DATA__
29
42
324
-511
32
354
0
-29
765
17
-32
```

Comment: Please read [mcve]. (Specifically: Describe the problem. "No such luck" is not a problem description.)

Comment: You know this would be much easier without regexes, right?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the numeric comparison operator `<=>` which returns -1, 0, or 1 according to whether the first operand is less than, equal to, or greater than the second, respectively. If you use it to compare each value to zero and add one to the result then you can index into an array

Like this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my @counts;

++$counts[($_ <=> 0) + 1] while <DATA>;

my ($ctrN, $ctrZ, $ctrP) = @counts;

printf "freq(Z+): %4d\n", $ctrP;
printf "freq(Z-): %4d\n", $ctrN;
printf "freq(0):  %4d\n", $ctrZ;
printf "Total:    %4d\n", $ctrP + $ctrN + $ctrZ;

__DATA__
29
42
324
-511
32
354
0
-29
765
17
-32
```

#### output

```
freq(Z+):    7
freq(Z-):    3
freq(0):     1
Total:      11
```

Answer (score 0):

Swap `$ctrZ++;` and `$ctrP++;` lines:

```
    # ...................
    elsif ( $num =~ /^[1-9]\d*$/ ) {
            $ctrP++;
    }
    else {
            $ctrZ++;
    }
    # ...................
```

Comment: My instructor asked for it to be in that exact order, and he didn't want the regex for $ctrP.

Comment: @MatthewParise that doesn't make sense. If P is for positive ints this answer is correct.

Comment: Just following instructors direction.  Trust me, im with you on this one.